# How can i filter with a key through JSONArray

Tags: java, json, org.json

Im getting the next error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException:
class org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to class
org.json.simple.JSONObject (org.json.simple.JSONArray and
org.json.simple.JSONObject are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

The endpoint where im getting JSON is:

https://www.okex.com/api/spot/v3/instruments

I have searched about the error, I think the problem is that I am getting a JSONArray instead JSONObject, but I need to filter by key, as I need to get every "base_currency" from json.

Below is the original code which is giving me the error:

```
private String UrlBase = "https://www.okex.com/";
private URL url;
private String inline="";
private JSONObject jobj;
private JSONObject jobj1;
private Scanner sc;
private String Symbols = "api/spot/v3/instruments";
private String Param1= "base_currency";
private JSONArray arr;
private JSONArray arr1;
private JSONParser prs;
private HttpURLConnection conn;
private ArrayList Monedas = new ArrayList();
private Conexion conc = new Conexion();

public void CargarMonedasNuevasOkex() throws IOException {



    try {
        url = new URL(UrlBase+Symbols);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } 

    try {
        conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.connect(); 

    int responsecode = conn.getResponseCode(); 

    if(responsecode != 200) {

        throw new RuntimeException("HttpResponseCode: " +responsecode);

    }
    else{

        sc = new Scanner(url.openStream());

        while(sc.hasNext())
        {
            inline+= sc.nextLine();
        }
        sc.close();

        JSONParser parse = new JSONParser();
        try {

            jobj1 = (JSONObject) parse.parse(inline);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        arr1 = (JSONArray) jobj1.get(Param1);
        System.out.println(arr.get(0));
        for( int a=0; a<arr1.size(); a++ ) {

            jobj1 = (JSONObject) arr1.get(a);
        }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
arr1 = (JSONArray) jobj1.get(Param1);
```

do

```
arr1=job1 ;//or jsut use the same variable
```

oh and

```
jobj1 = (JSONObject) parse.parse(inline);
```

should be

```
 jobj1 = (JSONArray) parse.parse(inline);
```

then

```
 for( int a=0; a<arr1.size(); a++ ) {

      JSONOBject temp=  arr1.get(a));
      String currency= temp.get("base_currency")
 }
```

basically in the link provided you get a jsonArray not an Object containing an Array

Answer (score 0):

for your requirement getting value according key,you can try this below code it is modified according your JSON format.

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            Object object = parser.parse(inline);
            JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) object;

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
                JSONObject singleObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                System.out.println(singleObject.get("base_currency"));
            }
```